# Eclipse Debugger doesn't stop at conditional breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have this Java Code in Eclipse that I would like to Debug.

This is the code :

```
    public Double repulsion(Node n1, Node n2) {
    Double rep = 0.0;
    rep = Math.pow(K, 2) / distEuc(n1, n2);
    System.out.println("Répulsion : " + rep);
    listForcesRep.add(rep);
    return rep;
}

    private Double distEuc(Node n1, Node n2) {
    Double d = 0.0;
    Object[] n1Attributes = n1.getAttribute("xy");
    Double x1 = (Double) n1Attributes[0];
    Double y1 = (Double) n1Attributes[1];
    Object[] n2Attributes = n2.getAttribute("xy");
    Double x2 = (Double) n2Attributes[0];
    Double y2 = (Double) n2Attributes[1];
    d = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2)));
    return d;
}
```

I toggled a breakpoint at line : `rep = Math.pow(K, 2) / distEuc(n1, n2);` and I ran the debugger in its default values and it works fine.

The thing is that at some point the `rep` variable takes a value `NaN` and I need a conditional breakpoint in order to understand why.

I set the conditional breakpoint like this :

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

But when I run the debug, it skips the breakpoint and the loop keeps on going.

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about Java, so this is just a guess: in some languages (e.g., Python), `NaN == NaN` is always `False`. You need to check if rep is a number or use some method to check if it is NaN.

Comment: @iled yes there's a function `isNan()` that does the job, as @andrucz mentioned in his correct answer. Now it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `rep` is still equals to 0.0 in that line: `Double rep = 0.0;`

You need to put a conditional breakpoint at `System.out.println("Répulsion : " + rep);`, after calculating `rep` value, then when execution stops at that line, you "Drop to Frame" to execute again that method.

You should also use `Double.isNaN(rep)` or `rep.isNaN()` instead of `rep == Double.NaN`.